# SpringBoot RetryListener.onError() invoked without being configured at @Retryable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

I am using @Retryable at various service methods. Some of them need some action to be done before the retry happens. I use a RetryListener implementation to achieve this. Well, that ended somehow weird.

1. the listener's `onError()` is invoked though not configured
2. the listener's `onError()` is invoked for exceptions not present at `retryFor`

**issue 1.**

Here is the listener code

```
package com.example.springbootretrytest.service;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryCallback;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryContext;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("testServiceRetryListener")
public class TestServiceRetryListener implements RetryListener {

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

My expectation is that the RetryListener bean like from above is **only** invoked if it is configured like this

```
@Retryable(listeners={"testServiceRetryListener"})
public String doSomething(String someParam) {
    // do something
}
```

Instead now methods **without** any `listeners` argument at their `@Retryable` annotation lead to invoking each of the RetryListener beans I have in my application. I now have to provide each of the methods with a `listeners={"defaultRetryListener"}` to prevent invoking those others.
Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a way to configure listener invocation behaviour on another level?

**issue 2.**

Given the following method

```
@Retryable(retryFor = TestReasonAException.class, listeners = {"testServiceRetryListener"})
public String doSomething(String someParam) {
    // do something
}
```

The listener's `onError()` is invoked also for other exceptions like `TestReasonBException.class`  (no inheritence). Compared with the issue 1. this is less severe. I could handle it in my `onError()` implementation. Nevertheless, is this how it is intended to be?

Full sample code can be found at https://github.com/nullnullschmidt/spring-boot-retry-test.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are "as designed".

First, any listener beans defined in the application context (such as your `@Component` listener) are considered "global" listeners and applied to any/all `@Retryable` methods.

The javadocs explain how setting listeners on the annotation disable the use of the global listeners for this method.

```java
/**
 * Bean names of retry listeners to use instead of default ones defined in Spring
 * context
 * @return retry listeners bean names
 */
```

Second, the listener invocations are at a much lower level; the `onError()` method is called long before the decision as to whether the exception is retryable or not is made.

Not-retryable exceptions will also go to any configured `@Recover` method (immediately, rather than after any retries).

Comment: Though I felt this to be a bit counter intuitive at first, at least it is deterministic. Thank you for your precise explanation, Gary.